# Counting Pageviews for some urls

Tags: php, varnish

I'm loving Varnish, I have a bit of a problem though.

I'm counting pageviews  for some resource on my site. Pageviews increment are limited via session in order not to count multiple views for each user.

I've made some tweakings to the varnish conf and the cache would work neatly, but unluckily my previous counter will be nullified until the page will expire (and the pageviews in between lost like tears in the rain).

do you have any idea of how i could keep this feature?

i thought about an Ajax call, but that isn't the best option.

is there another way to do it that you can thing of?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Google Analytics Event Tracking

I would simply allow Google Analytics to [track the events](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). This allows you to track unique visits to the resource. I have implemented this with great success on many sites.

#### Documentation

```
_trackEvent(category, action, opt_label, opt_value)
```

**category (required)**
The name you supply for the group of objects you want to track.

**action (required)**
A string that is uniquely paired with each category, and commonly used to define the type of user interaction for the web object.

**label (optional)**
An optional string to provide additional dimensions to the event data.

**value (optional)**
An integer that you can use to provide numerical data about the user event.

There are more details on the [Event Tracking Guide page](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html).

#### Examples

Is implemented as javascript calls in the page like so:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'opt_label', 'opt_value']);

// or a worked example from the Event Tracking Guide
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Videos', 'Play', 'Gone With the Wind']);
```

### Google Analytics Data Export API

To retrieve the data you can use the [Google Analytics Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html). The API allows you to narrow the returned statistics for [certain `filters`](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceDataFeed.html#filters).

In your case you are interested in the following filters:

- ga:eventCategory
- ga:eventAction
- ga:eventLabel

So you could narrow it down with something like:

```
&filters=ga:eventCategory==AccessResource;ga:eventAction==Download
```

Which translates to:

```
WHERE ga:eventCategory = 'AccessResource' AND ga:eventAction = 'Download'
```

You can even try it out with the [API explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html) in the documentation.

Comment: it's a clean solution, but those pageviewes are meant for the users, they will create charts such as "most viewed imagews today" so i need to have them in my db

Comment: I have updated my answer to include details on how to get the data back out of Google Analytics to use for graphing etc. Hope that helps.

Comment: it's a pretty good idea theoretically, [un]luckily there are just too many objects to even start thinking about an external service that has to run every day... Showing rows 0 - 29 ( ~35,002,499 total 1, Query took 0.0268 sec)

Comment: That is a shame. I am using it just fine in a large and busy site. It allows me to forget about maintain logging tables etc. Sounds like you are AJAXing it then.

Comment: how many events do you track daily? how many objects? how long does it take to parse the data from google?

Comment: Apologies, but I am not allowed to give out numbers due to the legal documentation surrounding the job. You will need to do your own experiments there. I don't do any operations on the data from google, but merely cache the response as JSON, which then gets directly fed to a JS graphing API. Don't forget Google is giving you totals back and not a row for each hit so the actual data returned is minimal.